# How to effectively chain 3 ajax calls where One ajax call feeds the other Two ajax calls?

Tags: javascript, ajax, promise

I am trying to find the effective way of chaining 3 ajax calls where one ajax call feeds the other Two ajax calls.
Here is the scanario :

```js
//Invoke the ajax calls
firstAjax('mypage.gng','john-doe').then(secondAjax, thirdAjax).done(function(second_ajax_data, third_ajax-data) {
        console.log(second_ajax_data);
        console.log(third_ajax-data);
});

//Define our ajax calls

const firstAjax = function(urlAjax, userName) {

      return $.ajax({
              url: urlAjax,
              type: 'POST',
              data: userName
             )};

const secondAjax = function(sessionId) {

       return $.ajax({
              url: '/userLogins/getUserLogins',
              type: 'POST',
              data: sessionId
             )};

const thirdAjax = function(sessionId) {

       return $.ajax({
              url: '/userHistory/getUserHistory',
              type: 'POST',
              data: sessionId
             )};
```

Basically, the **firstAjax** call retrieves the *sessionId* and then it feeds it to the other **2 ajax calls** at the same time. With the implementation above i am not able to get the data returned by the last two calls.
I would appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this might work:

```
function send_ajax_request(data){
    $.ajax({
      url: "yoururl",
      type: "GET",
      dataType: "json",
      data: {
        data: data,
        csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'
      },
      success: function (json) {
        next_ajax(json['success']);

      },
      error: function (xhr, errmsg, err) {
        alert("Could not send URL to Django. Error: " + xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText);
      }
    });
```

}

```
function next_ajax(data){
$.ajax({
    url: "yoururl",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
      coord: JSON.stringify({ "info": data[0], "info2": data[1] }),
      csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'
    },
    success: function (json) {
      console.log(json)

    },
    error: function (xhr, errmsg, err) {
      alert("Could not send URL to Django. Error: " + xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText);
    }
  });
```

}

Basically, use your Ajax's sucess function to invoke the next Ajax request. Should work!

Comment: Your approach involves nesting which might get ugly if you have several ajax calls. Thanks for the feedback